# convert web service client from c# to php

Tags: c#, php, service, web

I have c# example how to use some web service. How will look this code into PHP?

```
PartnerAPI papi = new PartnerAPI();
ApiReqHeader arh = new ApiReqHeader();

arh.clientId = "99992222";

LoginAuthenticationInfo lai = new LoginAuthenticationInfo();
lai.login = "login";
lai.pwd = "password";

ServiceAccountInfo sai = new ServiceAccountInfo();
sai.Serviceaccount = "1234567890";

GetChildAccountInfoBySearchCriteriaRequest child = new GetChildAccountInfoBySearchCriteriaRequest();

child.serviceAccountInfo = sai; // customerInfo = customer;
child.reqHeader = arh;
child.loginAuthenticationInfo = lai;


GetChildAccountInfoBySearchCriteriaResponse resp = papi.GetChildAccountInfoBySearchCriteria(child);
```

---

This is only one file (only this code, Need to get onlu accpount informa)

I add classe but still not work. What is wrong in this code

```
 $papi = new SoapClient($url,
                    array(
                      "trace"      => 1,        // enable trace to view what is happening
                      "exceptions" => 0,        // disable exceptions
                      "cache_wsdl" => 0)        // disable any caching on the wsdl, encase you alter the wsdl server
 );
$arh = new ApiReqHeader();

$arh->client_id = "99992222";

$lai = new LoginAuthenticationInfo();
$lai->login = "login";
$lai->pwd = "password";

$sai = new ServiceAccountInfo();
$sai->Serviceaccount = "1234567890";

$child = new GetChildAccountInfoBySearchCriteriaRequest();

$child->serviceAccountInfo = $sai; // customerInfo = customer;
$child->reqHeader = $arh;
$child->loginAuthenticationInfo = $lai;


$resp = $papi->GetChildAccountInfoBySearchCriteria($child);
echo $resp;



class ApiReqHeader{
    public  $clientId;
}
```

Comment: This is not a "please convert my code for me" site. Show your attempts at writing this in PHP  and we can comment/help. But otherwise this boils down to "give me the codez"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the same classes for use in your PHP file, and you have included the files you need, this would most likely be the syntax:

```
<?php

    $papi = new PartnerAPI();
    $arh = new ApiReqHeader();

    $arh->client_id = "99992222";

    $lai = new LoginAuthenticationInfo();
    $lai->login = "login";
    $lai->pwd = "password";

    $sai = new ServiceAccountInfo();
    $sai->Serviceaccount = "1234567890";

    $child = new GetChildAccountInfoBySearchCriteriaRequest();

    $child->serviceAccountInfo = $sai; // customerInfo = customer;
    $child->reqHeader = $arh;
    $child->loginAuthenticationInfo = $lai;


    $resp = $papi->GetChildAccountInfoBySearchCriteria($child);

?>
```

Obviously this won't just magically work unless you have the same files for use in your PHP application.